# Animating a CollectionViewCell Size To Outside CollectionView Boundary - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have been working on animating the size of some `collectionViewCells`. It is working great in my `collectionViewController`, but in another `UIViewController` where I have a small `collectionView` alongside other objects, the cell will only grow to the size of the `collectionView`. I would like it to fill the whole screen. What is the best way about doing this?

Here is my current code:

```
    var largePhotoIndexPath : NSIndexPath? {
    didSet{

        var indexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()
        if largePhotoIndexPath != nil {
            indexPaths.append(largePhotoIndexPath!)
        }
        if oldValue != nil {
            indexPaths.append(oldValue!)
        }
        collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
            self.collectionView?.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
            return
            }){
                completed in

                if self.largePhotoIndexPath != nil {
                    self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(self.largePhotoIndexPath!, atScrollPosition: .CenteredVertically, animated: true)
                }
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    if largePhotoIndexPath == indexPath {
        largePhotoIndexPath = nil
    }
    else {
        largePhotoIndexPath = indexPath
    }
    return false
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let dealImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: self.imageDataArray[indexPath.row])!
    let dealPhoto: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: dealImage)

    if indexPath == largePhotoIndexPath {

        var size = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        dealPhoto.frame == size
        return CGSize(width: 300, height: 525)

    }
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 175)
}



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.imageDataArray.count

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TrailInfoCollectionViewCell

    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: self.imageDataArray[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

And some images before and after I select the cell:

[image: Before Selection]

[image: After Selection]

As you can see, the image has grown to the size I want it, but it is constrained by the `collectionView`. Is it possible for a `collectionViewCell` to exceed the boundaries of a `collectionView`, or will I have to do it some other way? I would just set up a hidden `imageView` but I like the animated transition.

Thanks for your help. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clipsToBounds` properties is what prevents a subview from growing past it's parent. Set it to false and it should  work.

Comment: Hi Mika, thanks a lot for your comment. Sounds easy enough but what exactly should I change the BoundToView of? I have tried the cell and the image but BoundToView is not recognised. Sorry, I'm very new to this. Thanks a lot. Jon

Comment: Sorry. I typed that a bit fast on my phone. It's clipsToBounds. I will edit.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks. The only problem now is that the images aren't centred on the screen? Do you have any idea how I might do that? I thought the line `self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(self.largePhotoIndexPath!, atScrollPosition: .CenteredVertically, animated: true)` would do that for me but apparently not. Any extra help is much appreciated but thanks a lot for your help already.

Comment: I just realised my silly mistake. Using `.CenteredVertically` instead of `.CenteredHorizontally`. Thanks a lot for your help Mika